# Angular route error - POST http://localhost/angulav/public/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I want to do a login with Angular but as soon as i submit the form, i get this error in my console POST http://localhost/angulav/public/auth 500 (Internal Server Error).

This is my Route

```
  Route::any('/', function() {
    return view('layout.master');
  })->where('path', '.+');

Route::post('/auth', 'UserController@login');
```

This is my userController,js

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('userController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
 angular.extend($scope, {
    doLogin: function(loginForm) {
     $http({
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        url: 'auth',
        method: "POST",
            data: {
            username: $scope.login.username,
        password: $scope.login.password
             }
     }).success(function(response){
         console.log(response);
            });
          }
});
```

This is my html

```
 <form class="" ng-submit="doLogin(loginForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="login.username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="login.password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter username">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="username" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
 </form>
```

This is my usercontroller.php

```
public function login(Request $request)
     {
    $user_data = [
    'username' => $request->input('username'),
    'password' => $request->password('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($user_data)) {
        return response(Auth::user(), 201);
    } else {
        return response('username and password do not match', 403);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try with postman?

Comment: @PareshGami: please what is postman?

Comment: Postman is tool from where you can test your api because start development. just search in google postman for chrome

Comment: @PareshGami : ok so after installing, what next?

Answer (score 0):

Your content type is json which is a but you're sending through an object.
Where you have

```
data: {
        username: $scope.login.username,
        password: $scope.login.password
    }
```

change it to

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        username: $scope.login.username,
        password: $scope.login.password
    })
```

If that doesn't work, try change your header content type info to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json` and then parse your data object into the $httpParamSerializer function, see below. (dont forget to inject it).

```
data: $httpParamSerializer({
        username: $scope.login.username,
        password: $scope.login.password
    })
```